# Strange MySQL index used

Tags: indexing, mysql-8.0

I'm using MySQL 8 and I still have some doubts on how is choosing the index to be used on different queries

Table looks like:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `collection_stats` (
  `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `org_uuid` BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
  `project_uuid` BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
  `collection_name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `counter1` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `counter2` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `counter3` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `date_index` (`date` ASC),
  INDEX `org_usage_index` (`org_uuid` ASC, `date` DESC),
  INDEX `project_usage_index` (`org_uuid` ASC, `project_uuid` ASC, `date` DESC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `collection_usage_index` (`org_uuid` ASC, `project_uuid` ASC, `collection_name` ASC, `date` DESC))
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Idea is that I have some daily stats organized by organization, project, collection (an organization can have multiple projects and a project multiple collections).

I want to see the value of `counter1`, `counter 2` and `counter 3` per organization, per project or per collection in the last X days.

### Getting the stats for an organization:

```sql
explain SELECT 
    org_uuid, project_uuid, collection_name, 
    counter1, counter2, counter3 
FROM collection_stats 
WHERE 
    org_uuid = UUID_TO_BIN('bb5c2330-1a85-11e9-8ad9-b728a2ed4173', 1)  AND 
    date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

```
# id, select_type, table, partitions, type, possible_keys, key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra
'1', 'SIMPLE', 'collection_stats', NULL, 'ref', 'collection_usage_index,date_index,org_usage_index,project_usage_index', 'collection_usage_index', '16', 'const', '8', '100.00', 'Using index condition'
```

I see it's using the `collection_usage_index` instead `org_usage_index` but I have no explanation for it.

### Getting the stats at project level

```sql
explain SELECT org_uuid, project_uuid, collection_name, counter1, counter2, counter3 FROM collection_stats 
WHERE 
    org_uuid = UUID_TO_BIN('bb5c2330-1a85-11e9-8ad9-b728a2ed4173', 1) AND
    project_uuid = UUID_TO_BIN('faafad18-1a85-11e9-8a1d-b7281ece80f6', 1) AND
    date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)
```

Explain says the same . Using  `collection_usage_index` instead the `project_usage_index` ..

Any logical explanation for this . My table has only few rows for testing ? Might be the cause ?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a function in the `WHERE` clause. MySQL can't use functions and indexes as far as I know.
You can verify by changing `date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 10 DAY)` to `DATE >= $DATE` and check.

Comment: The left-most prefix shoudn't refer only to the columns into the WHERE clause ? Anyway removing the columns from SELECT as well doesn't bring any difference.

Comment: @silviu:I updated my answer. I had forgotten about mysql and functions

Comment: there is no change even if I remove the functions from where clause

Comment: It is hard to know why the optimizer chooses a certain approach. May be the `project_uuid` and `date` are not selective enough so it chooses the index with the `collection_name` too. Also you can force which index should be used